# The difference between the houses of Ancient Athens and Ancient Crete and how that was affected by woman's status

Tags: ancient-greece, architecture, women

I have been researching lately about woman in ancient Greece and I concluded that ancient Athenian homes were constucted in a way that assisted the lives of women, meaning they had many rooms to live in and had a good overview of the household, as they were expected to do by the society.
On the other hand, ancient Cretans had a different view on womanhood and their lives were different. How is that depicted in their architecture respectively?

Comment: Hi and welcome! This is an interesting question!!  Can you provide any more details on your initial research?

Comment: I can, but most of it is in Greek, whereas many people here don't speak this language, probably.

Comment: Are you asking us to provide evidence to support your theory that social expectations of women's duties affected architecture? Doesn't that devolve to architecture suits use?  ( Not rhetorical, sincere confusion.)

Comment: I'm asking if anyone noticed any differences between the two architecture/styles, which would be caused by the difference of the two statuses/stati for women.

Comment: When you say "ancient Crete", do you mean the Minoan age (3560–1400 BCE)? Assuming that for Athens you mean the period from roughly the 5th century BCE onwards, you are comparing two societies that are a millennium apart, different ethnicity, and architectures that are likely to be very different for a myriad of reasons other than the status of women in society. Knossos, for instance, shows little in the way of accommodating wheeled vehicles. It reminded me a little bit of what I once saw of the early excavations in Toumba, Thessaloniki - although those are probably even older than Knossos.

Comment: Yes I'm referring to the Minoans.